# Are opinion-based questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Many questions are about how to effectively learn a language. Some of them are voted for closing, since they are too opinion based.

Should this site be entirely based on studies, or should a level of experience and opinions be involved? I personally see value in opinion questions, since there are no right answers to a lot of these questions and even opinions can be helpful.

Comment: Good question. There needs to be a border for opinion based questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is good subjective and bad subjective

We are not a science site so not answers don't need to cite sources. [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) may request answers to cite sources but that's pretty much where the citing ends.

#### Opinion =/= Subjective

The close reason primarily-opinion-based doesn't discriminate all subjective questions. Key word: **primary**.

Some examples of **opinion**-based questions are:

- What is the best language to learn?
- Why does English suck so much for learners?

(these are exaggerated examples)

As you can see all these answers are **opinion** based. If I give you an answer, it will be what I think is the best answer.

**Attempts to cover up opinion-based questions**

If I change the question to:

- According to scientific research, what is the best language?

Well... that can be considered objective but the question is truly opinion based and this is really just a cover-up. **What is "scientific research**? A poll?

These are especially bad for the site's health as they result in unanswered questions (because chances are the study has not been done), and low quality content.

***What's wrong with opinion based?**

Stack Exchange is a Q&A forums, for *answers* not opinions. Opinion-based questions bring forth low-quality content such as "Why is English the worst language?".

#### What's good subjective?

As I said earlier, the only very objective questions are probably going to be going to be [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies). Good subjective **isn't** opinion based, meaning answers aren't simply a **binary preference** and bias is minimal. Examples are:

- [How can I prevent myself from forgetting a language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/132/21)
- [What are effective ways to memorize sign languages?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/95/21)

these are both subjective, as their is no cut and dry "way" to do, but they are the good type of subjective.

---

If you have disagreements or questions about what I said please leave a comment or ping me (@Downgoat) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37969/language-learning).

Comment: https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman . Try to come up with genuine examples of problematic questions.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm notice I added "(these are exaggerated examples)") ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a lot harder on a site like this than on most other SEs - on something like Stack Overflow, a question can be clearly objective - an answer will either work or it won't, but with language learning, a lot of techniques will vary from person to person (and probably from language to language) in their effectiveness.

Therefore I think we will get a lot more subjective questions here than on many other SEs, so should be more careful about closing questions for being opinion-based.